# Is it possible to get a user's location on nokiax without having to include the HERE maps sdk?

Tags: locationmanager, here-api, nokiax

I need to detect a user's coarse location (just the city and country) within the app. I have the normal android code using android.location.LocationManager class. But when I ported to NokiaX, the app does not report any location. The HERE sdk only talks about using the HERE maps (which I don't need)

Comment: Which changes did you do when you did the porting ?

Comment: I didn't make any change related to location stuffs.  I only used the gcm wrapper for push. I was expecting LocationManger will still work since I didnt use GooglePlayServices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this with following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

and with code:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

And it took less than 10 seconds to get first location in my balcony, and then it gets updates every second. Thus I don't see the problem in there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just confirmed I was using 2 providers (network and gps). GPS was off by default on my test device, and there was no SIM (for accessing network). My bad.